# Responsive Mobile Bootstrap Menu, moving content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

Using Bootstrap, I built a NAV menu. The menu works fine in on wide screens, but when the mobile collapsed menu is activated and you click the menu to open it, the content contained in the row with the class `moves_down_with_menu` moves down with the menu.  I would prefer the row not change when the menu opens.  I just want the menu to go over it.  However, I also want it to work exactly like it normally does otherwise.

How do I accomplish this?

http://jsfiddle.net/k98Bn/65/ is an example of what it's doing

EDITED: Added different sections

```
<section id='topbar'>
   <p> A black top bar with a message </p>
</section>
<section id='secondsection'>
<div id="hero" >
    <div class="jumbotron">
            <%= render 'shared/nav/nav_pages' %>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row moves_down_with_menu">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 marketing">
                    <h1>Some Title Test for display</h1>
                    <div id="heroform">
                        <%= render partial: 'shared/get_form', locals: {:get_form => get_form} %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section id='thirdsection' >
</section>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It would be helpful to have a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please post a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example** of your code that displays the issue.

Comment: @RunnyYolk Please see Jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

So after your comment I tweaked it...hopefully this is more what you were looking for... I had to edit some of the bootstrap class rules. Along with a couple horribly named utility classes ;)

essentially you just want to wrap the sections in their own relatively positioned containers. The navbar inside the relatively positioned container will be positioned absolute.

The section below the navbar will also be in the relative container with a top-offset the same height as the nave bar. If you are using a pre-processor like sass. Make the nav height a variable and reference that instead of static value. This is to ensure if you change the nav height, the section below adjusts automatically!

Hope this works out better for you this time!
link to the codepen https://codepen.io/stevebennn/pen/1f445118e4d8dbdec13149c0defd1197

```css
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1
}

.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00bcd4;
}

.relative-container {
  position: relative;
}

.margin-nuke {
  margin: 0;
}

.content-container {
  top: 50px; /* this is the height of the navbar. you should make it a variable so you know they are always the same :)*/
  background: #e3e;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and if my Nav menu was a top bar, I would agree.  However, it's actually underneath another section, so I am not sure how to address that.

Comment: so you're looking for |  jumbotron/hero > nav > content-area  | with that structure you do not want the nav to move the content area. correct?

Comment: I've updated the example above...let me know if thats what you were looking for

Comment: In my case, the jumbtron has an image and the menu Nav is contained with in the jumbotron.  This example has separated the two.  I modified my code and added min-height, so that the jumbotron can grow with the menu instead of staying fixed and it seems to be ok, but not exactly the solution I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position: absolute` to your navbar (you'll most like need to change the height and padding associated with your first Jumbotron as well).

> **absolute**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any,
>   or otherwise relative to the initial containing block. Absolutely
>   positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any
>   other margins.

See [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on MDN for more info.

**Example CSS:**

```
.navbar {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1500;
}
```

Alternatively you could add the Bootstrap class [navbar-fixed-top](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) to your navbar div (your navbar will scroll with the page though.)

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1500;
}
#hero .jumbotron {
  background: blue;
  height: 325px;
  margin: 0;
}
#hero .jumbotron .marketing {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#part2 .jumbotron {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="hero">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3.0 Skeleton</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row moves_down_with_menu">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 marketing">
          <h1>Some Title Test for display</h1>
          <div id="heroform">
            <p>
              This should not move with menu open
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section id='part2'>
  <div class='jumbotron'>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
      took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
      sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
      industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
      text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
      centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
      Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
      and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
      Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
      dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
      It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
      printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
      but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
      including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
      it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
      passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
      ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
      in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
      electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
      of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
      with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
      Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick I discovered is to give both the navbar and the main wrapper div an absolute position.

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1500;
}
```